# Why doesn't next () notify subscribers? rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to make a loading screen with an observable notifying when https requests finish but when I use next (false) to notify subscribers it doesn't notify

loading.service.ts

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService implements HttpInterceptor {

  loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  activeRequests: number = 0

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.activeRequests >= 0) {
      this.activeRequests++
      this.loading$.next(true)
    }

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.activeRequests--;
        this.loading$.next(true)
        if (this.activeRequests === 0) {
          this.loading$.next(false)
        }
      })
    )

  }

}
```

loading.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ComponentRef, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { LoadingService } from 'src/app/services/loading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.css']
})
export class LoadingComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  loadingSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    public loadingService: LoadingService,
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none'
    this.loadingSubscription = this.loadingService.loading$
      .subscribe(
        (status: boolean) => {
          console.log('status', status)
          this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = status ? 'block' : 'none'
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
        }, (err) => {
          console.log('err', err)
        }
      )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('unsubcribe')
    this.loadingSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }

}
```

ignore: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code

Comment: I tested your code and couldn’t find any problem it worked correctively for me can i ask you share your code in stackblitz or stuff?

Comment: https://github.com/FrancoRodao/administrador-empleados-frontend it won't let me import the project to stackblitz

Comment: Ok let me check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem was happened because you provide interceptor two times and i removed interceptor from loading.service.ts because was not correct place for more detail you can check these changes https://github.com/FrancoRodao/administrador-empleados-frontend/pull/1/commits/23d65d6926a764bc37c1e32acb269f3f8e7c15c8

Comment: Thanks man, I did not know that you could only have one provider

Comment: Do you know if I have several modules, could I have two interceptors ?, one in the app.module and another interceptor in another module

Comment: i know we can use multi interceptor but i can't describe, i think this one helps us https://medium.com/@swapnil.s.pakolu/angular-interceptors-multiple-interceptors-and-6-code-examples-of-interceptors-59e745b684ec